# Call PAPI_start() and PAPI_stop() in different functions?

Tags: c, papi

Usally PAPI is used like this:

```
Initialize Lib
Add Event(s)
PAPI_start()
someCalculation()
PAPI_stop()
```

However, I have an application which times code like this:

```
start = time()
someCalculation()
t = time() - start;
```

I want to override this time() function, which is in another file. My code:

```
static int INIT=0;
int retval;
static int eventSet = PAPI_NULL;
long long res[1];

if(INIT){
        // eventSet is NOT PAPI_NULL here!
        if ((retval = PAPI_stop(eventSet, res)) != PAPI_OK)
                handle_error(retval);
        return res[0]/1e9;
}

INIT = 1;
retval = PAPI_library_init(PAPI_VER_CURRENT);

if ((retval = PAPI_create_eventset(&eventSet)) != PAPI_OK)
    handle_error(retval);

if ((retval = PAPI_add_named_event(eventSet, (char *) "rapl:::PP0_ENERGY:PACKAGE0")) != PAPI_OK)
    handle_error(retval);

if ((retval = PAPI_start(eventSet)) != PAPI_OK)
    handle_error(retval);

return 0.0;
```

When running the application I get `PAPI error -9: EventSet is currently not running` from PAPI_stop().

I assumed that it would be sufficient to share the `eventSet` variable between the two runs of the function.
Unfortunately this doesn't seem to work as the event is not running when PAPI_stop() is called.

Is there any chance to fix this?

Comment: What happens when you call your timer the third time?  You stopped the events already.  You need to rethink your design, perhaps use `PAPI_read`

Comment: You are right! I had the false assumption that time() was only called twice. Thank you! (unfortunately I am not allowed to upvote your comment)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens when you call your timer the third time? You stopped the events already. You need to rethink your design, perhaps use `PAPI_read` –  Anycorn